# Link-only answers. New policy?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

I came across [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287193/861716). Current consensus says it's off-topic because it's a request for an off-site resource.

Due to the nature of the question, almost all of its answers are link-only answers, so I flagged a couple of them accordingly. To my astonishment most of these flags were declined.

I know site consensus at Stack Overflow is a dynamic thing. I've seen things change and I'm not surprised if they keep changing. So let me err on the side of caution and assume I missed something. I'm always open to learn. Could someone explain?

Comment: When the problem is the question, sometimes these flags get declined. The reasoning is that if the question asks for links, a link-only-answer can't be NAA. It leads to these situations and it's rather inconsistent IMO; but this is not a recent change.

Comment: @yivi Sounds reasonable, but yeah, inconsistent. If someone asks for "gimme the code" it's usually not well-received if people actually do that. Of course, at the time of asking anything went and answerers did nothing wrong, but I don't think we should have to look at the age of the question to decide how to flag.

Comment: "There's really only *one* valid exception to this rule, and that's when the *question* is:

_Suggest me some tutorials where i can learn quick._

Don't get me wrong, it's still a bad answer - but when the question is kinda *asking* for bad answers this is to be expected. Close or flag *the question* and move on..." ([Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773))

Comment: The [official guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/7795130) have said for a long time not to use NAA for link only answers, but to first salvage it by editing the link's content into the question, then if that's not possible, flag for moderator attention explaining why. "Don't leave moderators guessing; be explicit, rather than using a generic 'not an answer' (NAA) flag. Do this only if you cannot improve the post yourself and the only possible solution is deletion."

Comment: To confirm: I declined these flags because you flagged almost every answer to a resource request question. That's really a waste of time for everyone involved, as it is the *question that is the problem*. Close the question, even vote to delete the question, but you can't fault the answerers for giving exactly what was being asked for, those clearly were answering the stated question.

Comment: What benefit do you have from deleting it? Obviously it did help a lot of people already. For sure the question as a whole is off-topic and should be closed as such, but the content should stay IMO.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for revealing this. In the mean time it may be clear I agree with everything that's been said here. SO is an intricate ecosystem, is all. The only thing I can do is keep learning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you're dealing with resource requests, always vote to close/flag the question - don't flag the answers. If you stumble over a resource request by finding an answer in the review queues, I'm not entirely sure what you're supposed to do with the answer. Personally, I just click skip and vote to close the question.

If you flag multiple answers, however, whether they're marked helpful or declined depends on the mod. I've had flags both declined and marked helpful, though mostly on questions where I didn't perceive it as off-topic until the mod made it clear. If you're in doubt about the question, you can always ask someone for a second opinion.

That being said, if the answer clears the review queue naturally, link-only answers on off-topic questions are likely to be deleted. There's three deleted answers to that question which likely entered the review queue (two are likely, one is guaranteed because it has a comment from the VLQ review queue). It is inconsistent, yes, but it seems that closure has become more common in newer times compared to just deleting the answer when there's mods involved.

Link-only answers are technically answers to a question that requests them. Again, it's better closing the question in cases like these than flagging the answers, as closing the question normally takes 5 (until mid-september 2019, it takes 3) close votes, followed by up to 10 deletion votes on the question if the community agrees to just get rid of the entire off-topic mess, compared to spreading out several reviews and deletion and recommend deletion (for <20k users) votes on the answers and eventually the question.

**TL;DR:** Prefer closing those types of questions rather than flagging the answers